# No server certificate verification method has been enabled - Kali - OpenVPN

Tags: kali-linux, openvpn, certificates

I am trying to install OpenVPN. I downloaded one .vpn from Deutch. Then just did on the terminal with this file

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[~/Downloads/VPNBook.com-OpenVPN-DE4]
└─# openvpn --config vpnbook-de4-udp53.ovpn
```

I read the solution as:
Add the following line to your client configuration:

```
remote-cert-tls server
```

But I do not have any client config! See:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open up your vpnbook-dev4-udp53.ovpn file and add the following lines at the end:

1. remote-cert-tls server
2. tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"